# ConstraintLayout - how to align centers of two views vertically

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have two views - A and B. They have different heights.

How to vertically align the centers of these views inside `ConstraintLayout`?

For example, in the XML below, I would like the center of `img_change_picture` to be aligned with the center of `txt_change_picture`.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline_icons"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1"/>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_change_picture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline_icons"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img_header"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/settings_main_vertical_spacing"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/change_picture"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_change_picture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline_text"
    android:text="@string/settings_main_change_picture"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Post your xml please

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler, added the XML.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

1. Without Guideline, put attributes on every views that you need to align vertically.

   ```
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
   ```
2. With Guideline

Add horizontal Guideline and make it vertically center with `layout_constraintGuide_percent`.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
     android:id="@+id/guideline"
     android:layout_width="1dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>
```

For every views, anchor them to guideline with attributes

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
```

With guideline, you have more flexibility, as you can change all views position easily by moving the guideline.

**Update:**

To align a view vertically center against another view then you just need to refer the view id in attribute. To align `txt_change_picture` vertically center against `img_change_picture`, you can change layout like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_change_picture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline_text"
    android:text="@string/settings_main_change_picture"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/img_change_picture"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/img_change_picture"

/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't want to center the views in the parent. I want to position view A, and then position view B relative to A, such that the vertical center of B is the same as vertical center of A.

Comment: Thanks. Looking at it now, I could have figured out it myself cause I know how to center in the parent.

Answer (score 12):

*Android Studio 3.5*

*If it's TL;TR...*

Select your desired views, right button [image: press]:

And you'll get:

[image]