# Two columns with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I'm doing the Udacity Android for Beginners (Java) Lesson 3, "make an app interactive", the course is "PracticeSet TeamA and TeamB" a small counter for basketball game.

I need to make two columns for Team A and Team B with ConstraintLayout, I actually did one column with ConstraintLayout, it works well but I really wondering how to do 2 same columns like this:

```
 Team A     Team B
Button1A   Button1B
Button2A   Button2B
```

Some help would be very appreciate.

Pierre

Comment: use Guideline it is oky see below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48738176/constraintlayout-how-to-align-centers-of-two-views-vertically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions supposed.

1. Nested Layouts.

If you have already done *one column with ConstraintLayout*, place it in a horizontal LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ConstraintLayout />
    <ConstraintLayout />
</LinearLayout>
```

2. Using [Guideline](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#constrain-to-a-guideline) (as @vahab-balouchzahi commented).

I think the latter is better.

If you showed your actual *one column with ConstraintLayout*, I could show more detailed answer too, but without it I can only show such an outline.